# Find the ratio of areas in the $ABP$ and $PMCQ$ regions.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the figure, $(BM):(AQ)=(MC):(QC)$. calculate the ratio
of areas in the $ABP$ and $PMCQ$ regions.
[image]

My progress

$\frac{S_{ABP}}{S_{PMCQ}}=?\\
\frac{x}{y}=\frac{m}{n}\\
\\
\frac{S_{ABM}}{S_{AMC}}=\frac{x}{y}\\
\frac{S_{ABQ}}{S_{BQC}}=\frac{m}{n}\\
\frac{S_{ABM}}{S_{AMC}}=\frac{S_{ABQ}}{S_{BQC}}$

I couldn't develop from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of tricks which are useful for similar problems:

1. Affine maps preserve the ratios of areas and the ratios of lengths of segments on the same line, so you may assume without loss of generality that $\widehat{C}=90^\circ,AC=CB$ and $[ABC]=1$, for instance;
2. If we draw the diagonals of a trapezoid, there are important relations about the areas of the four resulting triangles.

[image]

The hyphotesis gives $MQ\parallel AB$, hence $CP$ meets $AB$ at its midpoint by (the converse of) Ceva's theorem. Let $\lambda=CQ/CA=CM/CB$. By [Van Obel's theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Gergonne.shtml) it follows that $BP/PQ=\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}+1=\frac{1}{\lambda}$. This leads to

$$ [AMB]=(1-\lambda)[ABC]=(1-\lambda),\qquad [APB]=\frac{1}{\lambda+1}[AMB]=\frac{1-\lambda}{1+\lambda}$$

$$[BMP]=[AQP]=\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}[AMB]=\frac{\lambda(1-\lambda)}{(1+\lambda)}$$

$$ [CQPM]=[ABC]-[AMB]-[AQP]= \lambda-\frac{\lambda(1-\lambda)}{1+\lambda}=\frac{2\lambda^2}{1+\lambda}$$

so

$$\frac{[APB]}{[CQPM]} = \frac{1-\lambda}{2\lambda^2}. $$

Comment: Thank you... a question.? If $A = 6, C = 2, CM = 3, BM = 9 \implies \lambda = \frac{1}{4}$ and therefore $\frac{[ABP]}{[CPQM]}=6$
but if $AQ = 6, CQ = 3, BM = 4, CM = 3 \implies \lambda =\frac{1}{2} \therefore  \frac{[ABP]}{[CPQM]}=1$, ie the area ratio depends on the segment values?? and so there would be no single answer in numerical terms?

Comment: @petaarantes: the ratio $[APB]/[CQPM]$ only depends on the ratio $\lambda=CQ/QA=CM/CB$.

Comment: Yes..I asked this because this question presented alternatives and one of them was $"1"$ but without knowing the reason for the $\frac{CM}{CB}$ segments, I can't say that.

Comment: Probably you forgot to mention that $M$ was intended to be the **m**idpoint of $BC$. In such a case $P$ is the centroid of $ABC$ and the ratio $[APB]/[CQPM]$ is pretty obviously $1$.

Comment: The statement is faithfully transcribed to the original. Probably then they forgot to provide this information..Thanks for the considerations

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Given, $\frac{BM}{AQ}=\frac{MC}{QC}$
so 
 $$\frac{BM}{MC}=\frac{AQ}{QC}=\frac{λ}{1}$$ (say)

 By Menelaus’ Theorem on triangle BQC,

 $$\frac{AC}{AQ}\frac{QP}{PB}\frac{BM}{MC}=1$$
which implies that $\frac{QP}{PB}=\frac{1}{λ+1}$.Similarly by Menelaus’ Theorem on triangle AMC, $\frac{MP}{AP}=\frac{1}{λ+1}$.

 By the property that ratio of areas of triangles with same height is equal to the ratio of their bases, we have $$\frac{ar(ABP)}{ar(APQ)}=\frac{λ+1}{1}$$,

 $$\frac{ar(ABP)}{ar(MBP)}=\frac{λ+1}{1}$$

 So ar(APQ)=ar(MBP). Let ar(APB)=(λ+1)k, then ar(APQ)=ar(MBP)=k. Now,

 $$\frac{ar(ABQ)}{ar(BQC)}=\frac{λ}{1}$$

 $$\frac{(λ+2)k}{k+ar(PMCQ)}=\frac{λ}{1}$$

 $(λ+2)k= λk+λ.ar(PMCQ)$ so that ar(PMCQ)=$\frac{2k}{λ}$. This implies that

$$\frac{ar(ABP)}{ar(PMCQ)}=\frac{λ(λ+1)}{2}=\frac{AQ•AC}{2QC^2}=\frac{BM•BC}{2MC^2}$$ where $\frac{AQ}{QC}=\frac{λ}{1}$ .

Comment: hank you... a question.? Does the relationship of the areas depend on the values ​​of the segments?? and so there would be no single answer in numerical terms? Because if we change the value of $BM$ and $MC$, the value of the relationship between the areas changes

Comment: thanks for the exercise solution

Comment: @petaarantes, strictly speaking, the final answer does not depend on the values of the segments, but their RATIO, as shown in the expression containing only λ. If you change the values of the segments keeping the RATIO same, the answer remains unchanged. No, there is no numerical solution unless the ratio AQ/QC or BM/MC is mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for answer